# Vb6 to C# migration: Normalizing an Old Access Db

Tags: database, ms-access, normalization

My existing application is a visual basic6  and Visual studio c++ based one for the automatic machines like pick and place machine using robots. It have a old database in MS Access where there are only 14 tables. But some of the tables have 90 odd fields and others are  mostly independent and separate. I have been given a task to normalize a Access DB efficiently as a part of migrating vb6 to C#.

It is my first time and I  have tried to read about it in the web. There were lot of information about the Normalisation and whether it is neccessary. After reading all, I have some confusions as to how to proceed

--> As My db involves mostly select operations, it is better not to over normalize the db,  But I have some tables having many fields. The maximum field is 255 in MS access.

Can someone tell me what are the factors I need to know or check before making an efficient reorganization of the Db.? If someone can provide a good source for any practical example for the normalization approach will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Microsoft Access includes a tool Analyse Table ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292799 ). You can use it to get an idea of where your tables may be improved. Make sure you work on a copy. You may also wish to read something like http://r937.com/relational.html, if you have not already done so.

Comment: i wouldnt suggest using MS Access Analysis as a 100%, or even a 75%, good suggestion.  It makes too many assumptions that do do not apply to all situational designs.  On VB6-C#, probably best to just print off all the code-behind/module/class sheets and start designing logic based off that information.  An inheritance/usage chart helps with this type of massive code upgrade.

Comment: You could add some links to that information you are referring, it might help someone trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Database normalization is a complex topic with many different tools and methods available to achieve your goal.  As you've pointed out in your question, there are a number of subtle issues to keep in mind, including not over-normalizing because it may have performance consequences.  While some automated tools can help you in simple situations, their output often leaves a lot to be desired.

My advice is to spend some time become more familiar with the topic of relational databases in general -- there are literally hundreds of good books (and probably thousands of good web resources) on the topic.  There's no substitute for digging in and really understanding the material.

But for a quick look at just the normal forms (which are the foundation of any normalization), this [Description of the database normalization basics](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878?wa=wsignin1.0) from Microsoft is a decent introduction to understanding what you're trying to achieve.